# Unable to load the xml because of empty value

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying load the below XML values

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
   <curmsg>
       <event> myevent </event>
       <clientid> 123456 </clientid>
       <appid> 1123456 </appid>
       <timestamp> December 13 2016 00:00:00 </timestamp>
       <clientname>  TEST ACCOUNT </clientname>   
       <accountnum> 123 </accountnum>   
       </backlink>    
       <key>AAAAC</key>
       <fileid>1234</fileid>   
       <filename>LKTEST1.1</filename>      
       <filesize>30</filesize>      
       <eekey>LKTEST</eekey>      
       <pjobid>DFSAQE3Z4</pjobid>    
       <filecategory>Proceed</filecategory>
   </curmsg>
</Data>
```

C# code:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmldata);
```

The above `LoadXml` function was throwing an exception because the `<backlink>` tag has only ending tag. It was working when I provided the starting tag but my requirement is I want to load the XML when tag has no starting tag (empty values).

Comment: That is not valid XML, why would you have and end tag without a start?  If you wanted that just do:<element />

Comment: so `</backlink>` without an opening tag is illegal. You can have a self closing tag `<backlink/>` - which means you don't need to explicitly add the closing tag for empty elements.

Comment: one of client is sending the above data to my MSMQ private queue ,  i want to read that above message without change.

Comment: As said, that's not valid XML.  If you know that </backlink> is going to be the only tag like that, you can do a String.Replace("</backlink>", "<backlink />") before parsing.  If that kind of thing is going to show up in other places, you may need to do some Regex matching or similar to fix the XML.

Comment: Not possible. Either you have to change the file manually, write code to look at the file before loading it as an xml or have your client fix it. It's bad XML - can't fix a turd

Comment: The XML is not well-formed.  You cannot read it using XML tools or libraries.  Tell the provider to fix the data -- **it's not XML** as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid XML and no built-in XML tools will be able to read it.

Your options:

- make whoever produces that file to create valid XML
- use `string.Replace` to replace broken nodes *before* loading it as XML (hacky, will likely break later when authors of the text file will introduce more invalid XML there).
- use more forgiving parsers - i.e. HtmlAgilityPack is explicitly designed to handle broken HTML and may be able to produce partial tree out of your text file.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

Why? Because `</backlink>` is not an empty tag. It's simply a syntax error. `<backlink/>` is an empty tag.

You probably want to use a correct XML file.